# How to save PyPlot figures to video file in Julia?

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I want to do something like the following using a loop and PyPlot to plot in figure windows.  My question is how to save the figure windows to a movie file within the loop?

```
using PyPlot

for k=1:5
  pcolormesh(rand(10,10)) 
  if k==1; colorbar(); end
  # save figure window to movie file here??
  sleep(.5)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by directly using the `animation` submodule of `matplotlib` (the underlying Python library that `PyPlot.jl` wraps). However, it is painful; see e.g. the following notebook (in Spanish):

https://github.com/dpsanders/fisica_computacional/blob/master/como_animar.ipynb

The simplest way, however, seems to be using `Plots.jl`:

https://github.com/tbreloff/ExamplePlots.jl/blob/master/docs/pyplot_examples.md#functions-adding-data-and-animations.

Comment: PyPlot works on a mac computer running Julia 0.3.9.  On windows  running Julia 0.4.0 neither PyPlot nor Plots work, each giving various errors with the using command.   Since 0.3.9 is working well with PyPlot on my mac computers I tried finding that same version's .exe for windows with no luck -- I'm not sure how to get it (although I did find the .exe for 0.3.8 for windows and again PyPlot and Plots don't work there).  Also on my windows computer with 0.4.0, Plots will run as a package but once I invoke the heatmap function the whole program shuts down.  Not sure where to go from here !

Comment: Ouch. Have you checked the `PyPlot.jl` README and issues about these problems? (https://github.com/stevengj/PyPlot.jl). If you don't find the particular issue there, you should file a new issue. Same with `Plots.jl`. I have no idea about Windows issues. You can also ask on the julia-users mailing list, since there are some Windows experts there.